# How to get past a locked door in Fort Hagen Command Center?

Tags: fallout-4

I’m playing through Fallout 4 again, and I’ve come across a bug in the game that’s preventing me from proceeding.

While playing the quest “Reunions”, I fought my way through Fort Hagen, all the way down to just before the boss fight with Kellogg.

Just before I engaged him, I went back to Sanctuary to drop some stuff, rest up, and grab some gear. Now that I’ve returned, there is a locked gate just as you enter the Fort Hagen Command Center, down the hall to the right.

The gate was open before, and there are dead synths all over from the last time I was there, but there is no way to open this gate now. It’s not controlled by a terminal or anything like that. In fact, I’m not sure I had to do anything special to open it before that I remember.

How do I get past this so I can fight Kellogg and complete the quest?

Comment: It's possible you triggered a cell reset and permanently broke the quest. Not sure if there's a way to fix it without console commands.

Comment: @Nelson; What console commands would I use? I tried setOpenState on it but it did nothing. Probably because it’s not a regular door.

Comment: Can't you just unlock the gate with the console? Use `unlock` command for it.

Comment: You should never leave a building when you're on an active quest which is related to it, it can mess up the quest permenantly. Also, Always save before entering buildings so if the worst happens, you can always reload the save.

Comment: *setstage 000229E7 2000* or *setstage MQ106 2000* - or something other than 2000 if you want to still try and do the rest of the quest.  ... see here for the stage numbers :  [Reunions](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Reunions)

Answer (score 1):

Open console, the tilde key on keyboard.  type tcl (To clip through walls, doors, etc.),  walk through door, and immediately after you are through, open console again and type tcl again.  Now you are through door, and back on solid ground.  Continue with quest!

Answer (score -2):

You broke the quest-line ..F5 quicksave always unload carried items onto companions. If pc is involved as u play it on pc.

"Settings" rest and wait can heal. Use console commands to clip though locked door "tcl" remember to revert hence you go through and watch which way you move ~,tcl, enter/move though~,tcl,enter~ and then V.A.T.S Kellog as his terminal will give you relivant info and looting to get required quest item ( why there two when one is required) is a Bethesda thing up elevator watch Pridwen

Certain companions hack, others pick locks, some fight well others don't. Check their stats. Macready is a sniper eg: give him rifle and let him do his thing deacons full of it, entertaining yes,ok in a fight but useless at picking and hacking.

If not on PC I'm not sure how to enter them on consoles.

Player mod carrywieght 1000 or god mode.

Comment: Hi Chris, your answer is all over the place. I'm not sure what exactly you're saying. Can you [edit] your post to make it clearer? I've removed most of the tangents and fixed the spelling/grammar mistakes, but it's as far as I can go without putting words in your mouth